# Can't find variable : require

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs

I am trying to integrate uber APIs on a website using javascript for getting info like cab fare or time required between 2 places.

I am very new to javascript. I am following the steps as shown on Github: 
https://github.com/shernshiou/node-uber#method-overview

It is the official recommendation from Uber.

When i am trying to do this :

```
var Uber = require('node-uber');
```

I get an error that can't find variable require.

I have tried to search on the internet but only lead that I have gotten is that 'require' is a function of node.js and I can use requirejs for getting the file but I haven't got any success yet.

Can someone help me?

Edited: 
Code :

```
function uberSignIn(){
  var Uber = require('node-uber');
  var uber = new Uber({
  client_id: '8CTT3TcU5RUcxsapr8wWZpwxVO8180aM',
  client_secret: '',
  server_token: 'nc4Bxk-HR6ja7EOA9MaAZvPI4sIizimiqiKGVfNX',
  redirect_uri: 'file:///Users/akshay/Desktop/dev_work/travelSathi/index.html',
  name: 'travelsathi',
  language: 'en_US', // optional, defaults to en_US
  sandbox: false, // optional, defaults to false
  //proxy: 'PROXY URL' // optional, defaults to none
});

}
```

Comment: Can you paste your complete code for this file?

Comment: Do you use Javascript or Node.JS ?

Comment: the Uber api is based on node.js but i am trying to extract it in javascript function has shown in question.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Browserify` to use that API wrapper which is for NodeJS. Otherwise, it's not compatible to use on web.

You can take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

You should set-up Nodejs on your computer. Then you need to install `node-browserify` as below;
`npm install -g browserify`.

Then in a simple way, you can use it as below;

`browserify uber-api-wrapper.js > uber-api-web.js`.

Your uber-api-wrapper.js should look as below;

`var Uber = require('node-uber');`

Comment: I think he don't use Node.js 

This will not work without Node.js server.

Comment: yes @AliBARIN, I want to extract the library itself.

Comment: Someone who down voted this answer. You should give a feedback. :)

Comment: @AkshayChugh You can also try http://stuk.github.io/require1k/ which doesn't require a build step or Node.js.